# Java abstract class defining array size

Tags: java, arrays, int, abstract-class

I have an abstract class and in that abstract class I have an array and I want every class that extends it to have the array 2 ints long no matter what. I know you can define array size in methods but thats all you can do it in. Here's some code

```
public abstract class entity{

int pos[]

// want this variable to be two ints long no matter what extends it
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instantiate the array in the superclass and limit the access to it with methods. That way no subclass can change the size of the array.

```
private int[] pos = new int[2];

protected void setPos(int index, int value) {
    pos[index] = value;
}

protected int getPos(int index) {
    return pos[index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the extending classes to initialize it? You can initialize it to `int[2]` in the super class itself.

BTW your class `entity` should be called `Entity`. `pos` can be `final` or `private` or both.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected final int[] pos = new int[2];
```

Declaring it `protected` ensures that all types that are derived from it will have access to it.

Declaring it `final` ensures that no derived type will change what the reference points to.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int[] pos = new int[2];
```